# How to download only specific tables from heroku PorstgreSQL backups?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

There is a way to exclude tables using `heroku pg:pull` (`--exclude-table-data`).

But how about backups if I need to get some data from the past?

`heroku pg:backups:download` does not seem to have an option to select tables to download.
Is there a way to download only some part instead of having to load gigabytes of data if I only need small chunk?

Answer (score 0):

`heroku pg:backups:download` is nothing more complicated than a wrapper to download previous dumpfiles you've created so what you're asking isn't possible. If you need to inspect the state of a table from the past, you *might* have a couple options.

1. Run `heroku pg:backups:download` to download the dumpfile and use `pg_restore` locally to rehydrate a single table. It sounds like this isn't ideal for you and you're already aware of it but I included it for the sake of completeness.
2. If you're using a standard (or higher) database and the historical state that you'd like to inspect is within the rollback (docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-rollback#creating-a-rollback-database)) window you could create a rollback fork of your database and `psql` directly to the fork and dump a single table that way.

Answer (score 0):

Backup Heroku DB and download (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups)

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
```

Import single table from Heroku Backup into local DB via pg_restore (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)

```
pg_restore --verbose --data-only --table TABLE_NAME --no-acl --no-owner 
    -h localhost -U DBUSER -d DBNAME latest.dump
```